# How to "decode" this ancient log of Apollo Guidance Computer (AGC)?

Tags: apollo-program, telemetry, agc

I found this interesting document:

https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Documents/apollo_11_computer_words.pdf

But the scan quality is very very poor!

[image: scan 1]

[image: scan 2]

[image: scan 3]

I tried interpreting the headers, but some characters are really unreadable...

[image: header]

**Does anybody know if a better copy of this document exists? Or does anybody know a method to improve readability enough to allow OCR? Or, as a last chance, is anybody interested in helping manually transcripting the document number by number?....**

Additionally, **does anybody know where to find the list of "elements numbers" mentioned in this log?** It would help understanding the headers.

I would like to write an "AGC replayer" which allows replaying the whole power descent as it really happened. It's different than a typical AGC simulator or emulator, which just waits for user input, my replayer could be used side-by-side with an AGC emulator to try exactly replaying the Apollo 11 landing.

I also would like to write the AGC log together with voice transcript of the landing; as of now I was only able to do it for last seconds of power descent:

[image: landing]

Comment: I'm reasonably sure it's "Accel. about Z body axis" and "Accel. about Y body axis". Interesting project!

Comment: Also, you can consider asking the maintainer of the scan repository (Ron Burkey) if he has a better quality version available. From my experience he's pretty responsive.

Comment: found raw highres images: https://archive.org/download/apollo_11_computer_words

Comment: Wow https://archive.org/details/virtualagcproject is a treasure trove. Thanks.

Comment: Found another treasure :-)  https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Don+Eyles%22  Don Eyles is "just" THE person which knew what 1201 and 1202 meant, and he knew in realtime during Apollo 11 landing.

Comment: A cute, little, ancient and forgotten DSKY simulator will allow me to replay the powered descent in the browser! :-) https://github.com/jumpjack/dskysim

Comment: @jumpjack nice find; throw-back to the nineties, when pages were simple!

Comment: My current work on this topic: https://github.com/virtualagc/virtualagc/issues/1155